freeze_support ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
I'm a new to python and try to write an app using PyQt6 and multiprocessing.
It works well in editor,but get error when run exe.
pyinstaller 6.10.0   python 3.12.5   pyqt 6.7.1   windows11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 43, in _freeze_support
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
[PYI-31452:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'application' due to unhandled exception!

the following is my code:

application.py

import sys
import multiprocessing
import gui
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    gui.Gui().setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


gui.py

import sys
import concurrent.futures
import backend

sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None
        pass  # more code

    def setupUi(self, mainwindow):
        initialization_multiprocessmanager_thread = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        initialization_multiprocessmanager_thread.submit(self.initialization_multiprocessmanager, )
        mainwindow.setWindowTitle("title")
        mainwindow.resize(1200, 680)
        pass # more code

    def initialization_multiprocessmanager(self):
        try:
            self.process = backend.Backend()
            print('backend done')
        except Exception as e:
            print('backend', e)


backend.py

import multiprocessing

class Backend:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict1 = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
        self.dict2 = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
        self.dict3 = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

    def worker(self):
        pass  # more code

after hours testing, i found this line is causing the issue:
sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']
if i remove this line,everything is ok, if added, got that error
why and are there any other solutions?

What do you use those lines for?

why don't you remove that line and change it to: app = QApplication(sys.argv + ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1'])
